# Scrollbar Table checkpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I want to design a table with checkpoints that is it should be able to bring up 'x-th' row when the value is entered/jum x-rows on click .It is a scrolling table like:

[JS Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/k42ba/)

With every Next click it should jump 'x-rows'
Can anyone suggest someway out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. check that. It is working as per your requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/k42ba/2/

**CODE:**

```
var len = $('tr').length;
var index = 1;

function selectRows(start,end){
  $('tr').not($('.tblhead')).hide();
  $('tr').slice(start,end).show();
}
selectRows(index, index + 5);

$('a#next').click(function(){
    if(index < len -5){
    index = index + 5;
    selectRows(index, index + 5);
    }
});

$('a#prev').click(function(){
    if(index > 1){
    selectRows(index-5, index);
    index = index - 5;
    }
});
```